# execute ussd from shell-script

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, scripts, ussd

Every month I need to execute USSD-command. I want to automatize it. My idea is to write shell-script for [SManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager&hl=en). I found two ways to make a call (tested from adb):

```
service call phone 2 s16 '*100#'
```

and

```
am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:*100#
```

But this commands **call** to `*100#` instead of execute ussd.

My Android is `4.2.2`, rooted Cyanogen `10.1.3`

Answer (score 2):

replace `#` to `%23`, so:

```
service call phone 2 s16 '*100%23'
```

or

```
am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:*100%23
```

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this? Coincidentally, I need the exact same thing, "call" the USSD code, and based on the parsed output, select some USSD menu options (most likely using input command).